# can't send Array to Controller

Tags: javascript, forms, api, vue.js

```
let data = new FormData();

payload = JSON.stringify(payload.unitDoctors);
for (var key in payload) {
  data.append(key, payload[key]);
}
axios({
    method: "put",
    url: apiPath + payload.id,
    data: data
  })
    .then(response => {
      commit("updateItem", response.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      commit("setErrors", e.response.data);
    });
}
```

**when i send formData to api controller unitDoctors(array) always null. Any Idea ?**

Comment: please post an example of the response data from the API. 
"payload = JSON.stringify(payload.unitDoctors)" stringifying part of a json object referenced by key seems problematic to me. I'm confused what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to loop over a string, as you've already called JSON.stringify there. Maybe get rid of that stringification call? It's hard to tell what the actual problem is without seeing your data and the desired result.

Comment: from the code it looks like they are turning the json object into a string that is only one key from the original json object, no?